# How do I use today's entered data in excel for a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I have a table that is 30 rows long in a column. Every day I enter my weight. So day 1 I entered my weight into A1, day 2 into A2 and so on.

Now I want to calculate some things based off of this, such as show "Current weight:", "Current BMI:", "Projected weight loss:" and so on. But to do that, I need to use the latest entered value. I have another row, called "Date" that shows the date next to each weight input. So right now I have 30 dates because my table is 30 rows long but only 2 weight values since I made the sheet yesterday.

So my question is: how do I pick the weight that is next to the date that is equal to today's date for when I want to use it in a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

we are recording values daily.

In **D1** enter:

```
=TODAY()
```

and in **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,A:A,0))
```

This will give you the weight value for today:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. My date is in B and weight is in C. And I wrote =Today() in X15. So I typed:

=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(X15,B:B,0)) but it says it is an invalid formula. Can you see where I've done wrong?

Comment: I have found the problem. My Excel wants ; instead of , so this fixed the problem: =INDEX(C:C;MATCH(X15;B:B;0)). Thank you again.